# Bot Telegram. Funcion retorna lista vacía

Tags: python, lista, sqlite3, telegram

estoy programando un bot para mi proyecto final de máster el cual en una de las funciones hace uso de una base de datos SQLite3 muy sencilla (2 columnas). La función que hace la query a la bbdd está en otro módulo y funciona perfectamente.

El problema viene al integrar ese módulo/función en el bot, dado que los datos de la query se añaden a una lista y la lista retorna vacía.

Código de la función del bot:

```html
def search(bot, update): #bot y update son parámetros propios del bot.
    
    bt=update.message.reply_text #El bot manda un mensaje al usuario.
    games=search_game('dark souls')
    bt(games)
```

Código de la función de búsqueda:

```html
def search_game(args):
    
    print('A')
    
    temp_list=[]
    db=sqlite3.connect("FitGirl.db")
    cursor=db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GamesDB (Title UNIQUE, Magnet)""") #Esta línea es innecesaria realmente, pero sin ella el bot me dice que no existe la tabla GamesDB...
    sentence='SELECT Title FROM GamesDB WHERE Title LIKE ?'
    cursor2=cursor.execute(sentence, ["%{}%".format(args)])
    
    print('B')
    
    counter=1
    for i in cursor2:

        print('C')

        ii=str(i)
        ii=ii.replace("('","") #Al devolver listas tengo que limpiar caracteres.
        ii=ii.replace("',)","")
        temp_list.append(str(ii))
        counter+=1

    print('D')
    
    return temp_list
```

Desde la consola puedo ver como se imprimen A, B y D, pero C no, es como si se saltara el loop. Lo más extraño de todo es que me sucede lo mismo leyendo de CSV y retornando JSON.

Llevo 2 semanas sin avanzar y ya he quemado internet buscando respuestas y alternativas. A ver si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No queda clara la parte de create table. Si algo indica que la tabla no existe entonces es probable que estes creando una tabla en cada llamada a la función y, por ende, el cursor no este devolviendo ningún registro.

Comment: Esa línea tuve que incluirla para que al ejecutar la búsqueda desde el bot no me devolviese el error de que no existía la tabla (cosa que al ejecutar el módulo en Spyder no sucede).

Si incluyo la parte de la búsqueda como otra función más dentro del bot también se salta el bucle for. Sin embargo otro bucles los recorre, por ejemplo declarando una lista dentro del propio código.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de descubrir de donde viene el fallo...

En la línea:

```
db=sqlite3.connect("FitGirl.db")
```

Debía poner:

```
db=sqlite3.connect(r"C:\Users\n40k1\Documents\FitCodexBot\FitGirl.db")
```

Dos semanas para esto. Menuda broma.